# Update records details using Oracle 10g DB and VB.net

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010, oracle10g, sql-update

I am trying to figure out how to get some output as to what records were updated when running this query:

```
UPDATE   CSR.TARGET ces 
SET      (STATUS_CODE, COMPLETE_DATE, DATA) = 
     (SELECT    'ERROR', '', REPLACE(c.Data, ' x</csr', '</csr') 
     FROM       CSR.TARGET C 
     WHERE      (c.EID = ces.EID) 
     AND        c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR') 
WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM     CSR.TARGET C 
WHERE    (c.EID = ces.EID) 
AND      c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR')
```

If there are 3 records that were updated by that above query then i would like to know what they were (record ID, etc). How would i go about doing that?

Currently it just tells me 3 records were updated and thats it. No other details.

Any help would be great! Thanks :o)

**UPDATE**

I am needing this for a query using VB.net so i do not think i can do PL/SQL type of thing?

```
    Dim OracleCommand As New OracleCommand()
    Dim ra As Integer

    OracleCommand = New OracleCommand("UPDATE   CSR.TARGET ces " & _
                                      "SET      (STATUS_CODE, COMPLETE_DATE, DATA) = " & _
                                                "(SELECT    'ERROR', '', REPLACE(c.Data, ' x</csr', '</csr') " & _
                                                "FROM       CSR.TARGET C " & _
                                                "WHERE      (c.EID = ces.EID) " & _
                                                "AND        c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR') " & _
                                      "WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT 1 " & _
                                      "FROM     CSR.TARGET C " & _
                                      "WHERE    (c.EID = ces.EID) " & _
                                      "AND      c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR')", OracleConnection)

    Try
        ra = OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        OracleConnection.Close()
 ....
```

David

Comment: AFAIK, you can use the returning into clause (applies to PL/SQL). Check the xample @ http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

Comment: FYI: your OracleConnection.Close() code should be in a Finally block.  Otherwise the connection will remain open if the call to ExecuteNonQuery() throws an exception.

Comment: PL/SQL is what is inside your sql string - you can certainly use all pl/sql features from vb.net

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: Could you show an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the RETURNING clause.  Assuming that the `EID` column is the "record ID" you're referring to and that it is numeric

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE num_tbl
IS 
TABLE OF NUMBER;

DECLARE
  l_modified_eids num_tbl;
BEGIN
  UPDATE csr.target ces
     SET <<omitted>>
   WHERE <<omitted>>
   RETURNING eid
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_modified_eids;

  <<Iterate through l_modified_eids to see which rows are modified>>
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of that query, all records that have an EID that matches the EID of a record who's status_code is 'ERROR' will be udpated.  So if you have a table like this:

```
ID   EID  STATUS_CODE
--   ---  -----------
 1     1    ERROR
 2     1    OKAY
 3     2    OKAY
```

both records with ID 1 and 2 would be updated, because 2's EID field matches 1's EID field, and 1's EID field shows error.  When it updates, it always uses the data from the row with the 'ERROR'.

Comment: I think that is likely what the query is intended to do - in any EID has ERROR, show that ERROR for all records with that EID, so we're sure it's not missed.  Whether or not that's a good idea depends on what the data represents.  The only possible error I see is that if there are two rows with the same EID that both have an ERROR status code, you might have unexpected results.

Comment: Well it seems to work as it should currently :o) Just need feedback as to what was updated.